# Why temporary is created in the following example

Tags: c++

Could you please explain (better in terms of standard) 
why temporary is created in the following example in line marked with comment?

```
class A
{
public:

    bool operator<(const A& rhs) const {return true;}

};

set<A> s;

int main()
{
    s.insert(A());
    set<A>::iterator pos;
    pos = s.begin();
    (A)*pos;              // why temporary created here?

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of every conversion to an object type is a temporary.

Beware that Microsoft Visual C++ is non-compliant to this rule, when the conversion is an identity conversion.  I've reported [a bug on Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/615622/identity-cast-to-non-reference-type-violates-standard) which also shows the rules in the standard that require creation of a temporary:

> The result of the expression `(T)` cast-expression is of type `T`. The result is an lvalue if `T` is an lvalue reference type or an rvalue reference to function type and an xvalue if `T` is an rvalue reference to object type; **otherwise the result is a prvalue**.

(section 5.4 `[expr.cast]` of the Standard, the `xvalue` language was added in C++11 but the creation of a temporary in this case has always existed)